# Loop date by shell script and process copy file from the client SFTP to our SFTP

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, sh

I have some problems with how to process a copy file from the client SFTP server to our SFTP server and move it to a specific folder. 
In this case, I need to run a shell script monthly at 11 every month.

What I need are.

1. How do we loop in a shell script between the start date and the end date if we already set two parameters as input?
   The first parameter is the file name. "_DAILY_REJECT.csv"
   The second parameter is this month and year. "MMYYYY"
2. How do I concatenate the second and first parameters? So the full file name to get is DDMMYYYY_DAILY_REJECT.csv.

Example: I need to get the file from 12012024_DAILY_REJECT.csv to 11022024_DAILY_REJECT.csv.
Shell script params: _DAILY_REJECT.csv 022024
In my understanding, it should be like this:

```
filename=$1
month=$2
start=12012024
end=11022004
while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
 echo $start
 # concatenate date with file name
 # Check if the file exists.
 # get file
 # Move the file to a specific path.
done
```

I hope you can help me resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem and don't need second parameters.

```
filename=$1
start="$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01 -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 month")" +%Y%m)12"
end=$(date +%Y%m)11
while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
 echo $start
 startD="${start:6:2}"
 startM="${start:4:2}"
 startY="${start:0:4}"
 startW="$startD$startM$startY"
 full_filename="${startW}$1"
 # Check if the file exists
 # get file
 # Move the file to a specific path.
 start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
done
```